# Resource in www not found

Tags: ionic-framework

I am developing an mobile application using ionic framework. However, I got the error message `file:///modules/moduleName/view/modal.html` not found after i deploying to mobile app. I instantiate it as follow in the controller.

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('../../../modules/moduleName/view/modal.html');
```

where modules is in www directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project structure is like below:

```
PROJECT_NAME
    www/
        modules/
            moduleName/
                view/
                    modal.html
        ...
        index.html
    ...
```

You should just use `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modules/moduleName/view/modal.html');` wherever your controller is. The path to your project file should be relative to `index.html`.